# Nested for loops and parameter values

Tags: java, jsp

I've been troubleshooting the following code and cannot figure out why nothing is showing up in the ArrayList unavDays. Any help is appreciated.

I've tested individual pieces:

- the first if statement evaluates to 'true'
- unavTimesConv.size() / 2 == 1
- unavDaysTemp[0].equals("M") == 'true'

I know that the ideas behind the code might be hard to understand without the full picture. I'm hoping that I overlooked a small syntax error. Thanks

```
List<Integer> unavTimesConv =  new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<String> unavDays =  new ArrayList<String>();
String[] unavDaysTemp = request.getParameterValues("days");


if(request.getParameterValues("days") != null)
{        
    for(int i = 0; i < (unavTimesConv.size() / 2); i++)
    {
        for(int j = (7*i); j < (7*(i+1)); j++)
        {
           if(unavDaysTemp[j].equals("M")) 
           {
               unavDays.add("M");
           }
           else if(unavDaysTemp[j].equals("T")) 
           {
               for(int k = 0; k < 1; k++) {unavDays.add(null);}
               unavDays.add("T"); 
           }
           else if(unavDaysTemp[j].equals("W")) 
           {   
               for(int k = 0; k < 2; k++) {unavDays.add(null);}
               unavDays.add("W"); 
           }
           else if(unavDaysTemp[j].equals("TH")) 
           {   
               for(int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {unavDays.add(null);}
               unavDays.add("TH"); 
           }
           else if(unavDaysTemp[j].equals("F")) 
           {  
               for(int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {unavDays.add(null);}
               unavDays.add("F"); 
           }
           else if(unavDaysTemp[j].equals("S")) 
           {  
               for(int k = 0; k < 5; k++) {unavDays.add(null);}
               unavDays.add("S"); 
           }           
           else {unavDays.add("Something busted");}

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Well, `unavTimesConv` is initially empty; so the `i` loop will never be entered, as `0 < (unavTimesConv.size() / 2)` is immediately false.

Comment: The OP claims it has been tested... There must be sth wrong with the test. `unavTimesConv.size() / 2 == 1` is not true.

Answer (score 0):

So your list is created as:

`List<Integer> unavTimesConv =  new ArrayList<Integer>();`

then obviously `unavTimesConv.size()` = `0`, as at the time of creation with default constructor list's size is 0, you iterate `i` from `0` till `0/2=0`, then any iteration won't happen as obviously

`0 < 0 == false`

i think you've just missed something when testing

`unavTimesConv.size() / 2`

It's actual size is 0 at the time of entering that cycle